# jquery auto cycle with prev and next buttons

Tags: jquery

I need a to create a slide show with previous and next buttons. So I found an example online. I tried implementing it but there is a part I dont understand: Cufon replacement. I dont know where to add the following code.

```
    // Cufon title replacement
    //Cufon.replace('#features .title')('h1')('h2')('#nav-main li a:not(#nav-main li div a)',{ hover: true })('.dropped-list .close')('.nav-segment p')('#hero .content p',{ hover: true })('.date');

    //hasSearched = false;



    if ($('.starter').length > 0)
    {
        $('.starter').cycle({
            fx:      'scrollLeft',
            timeout: 10000,
            next:   '#next', 
            prev:   '#prev'
        });
    }

                <div class="starter">
                    <img src="images/home_slideshow_1.jpg" alt="Slideshow 1" />
                    <img src="images/home_slideshow_2.jpg" alt="Slideshow 2" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Cufon-Javascript to your website:

```
<head>
(...)
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2-min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cycle.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cufon.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourjs.js"> </script>
(...)
</head>
```

The Cufon class is [here](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/js/cufon-yui.js), and yourjs.js will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Cufon.replace('#features .title')('h1')('h2')('#nav-main li a:not(#nav-main li div a)',{ hover: true })('.dropped-list .close')('.nav-segment p')('#hero .content p',{ hover: true })('.date');

    if ($('.starter').length > 0)
    {
        $('.starter').cycle({
            fx:      'scrollLeft',
            timeout: 10000,
            next:   '#next', 
            prev:   '#prev'
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
I see that you also need something like `fontname.font.js`, which can be generated at [Cufon's website](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)